# How to manipulate array of objects without loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a code like below and it is working fine.

```
 for(let i=0;i< this.Array.length ; i++){
          if(this.Array[i].propertyObject.hasOwnProperty('header'))
          this.Array[i].ColumnName = this.Array[i].propertyObject.header;
    }
```

May i know how to achieve the same with Map.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What makes you think you want to avoid a loop?

Comment: What about recursive functions?

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN - Ooooh, fair point!! :-) I mean, conceptually they're still loops, but they aren't *technically* loops.

Comment: :) to my eye that's a loop using the call stack, but 'formally' (as in for a sw interview) it can be the answer they're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May i know how to achieve the same with Map

I assume you mean [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `map` isn't the right tool for doing **exactly** what that loop does, because that loop modifies the array in place, but `map` creates a **new** array instead.

**If you want a new array**, perhaps also with new objects (e.g., functional programming or immutable programming):

```
// Replace `this.Array` with a new array
this.Array = this.Array.map(element => {
    // If we need to change this element...
    if (element.propertyObject.hasOwnProperty("header")) {
        // ...do a shallow copy along with the replacement
        element = {...element, ColumnName: element.propertyObject.header};
    }
    return element;
});
```

Note that that assumes the elements are simple objects. If they aren't, you'll need to handle constructing the replacement differently than just using `{...original}`.

**But if you want to keep the same array as your current code does**, your loop is just fine. You have other options (like `forEach` or `for-of`), but what you have is also fine. `for-of` is well-suited to what you're doing:

```
for (const element of this.Array) {
    if (element.propertyObject.hasOwnProperty("header")) {
          element.ColumnName = element.propertyObject.header;
    }
}
```

---

Side note: In new code, you might want to use [`Object.hasOwn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) rather than `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` (with a polyfill if needed for older environments; recent versions of all modern browsers support it natively, though).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Array.forEach((item, index, arr)=> {
       item.ColumnName = "header" in item ? item.header : item.ColumnName;
});
```

Comment: Then ColumnName doesn't change.

Comment: Throwing the correction up to see if it sticks.

Comment: There is still a slight difference here (suppose `ColumnName` is an accessor property, not a data property), but it's **very** unlikely to matter. :-) (I mean, it would with `innerHTML` on a DOM element, but `ColumnName` seems unlikely to be an accessor with that kind of side-effect...)

Comment: Though arguably `hasOwnProperty` could be overwritten and return something completly different as well ;)

Comment: @pilchard - LOL Or `header` could be inherited, but the OP doesn't want that. But now we're getting absurd. :-D